# Can't ship partially refunded Bundle product in magento

Tags: php, magento, bundle, product

So the store I am currently working on is using mostly bundle products. The child products are optional, so you can purchase part of the bundle as well.

The problem is, that when a order is made with a bundle product and a partial refund is made (for example only one product from the bundle is refunded) the whole bundle cannot be shipped. And to top it all, the order status becomes Complete, even though not a single item has been shipped from the order.

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2. Tested it both on the project I am working on and the default Magento installation. The same results on both.

Has anyone made some sort of a workaround for that? Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that issue? Maybe could point to a file where the fix might be applied?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Magento treats the bundle product as one. So you buy the parent item, and not the parts.

I am encountering the same problem trying to credit only part of it.